# How can we configure jsf in openbravo

Tags: jsf, openbravo

How can I configure jsf in openbravo? Is it possible?

If possible, could you guide me, since I am new to openbravo.

Answer (score 0):

[jBoss Seam](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Projects/Seam) integrates with Openbravo. [Seam](http://www.jboss.com/products/seam/) itself was brought to make easier integration of JSF with another technologies.

Comment: i should use apache tomcat 6.0 version.could u give me instructions to configure.